# How to use devise in an other model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm trying to implement devise login into a nav, but I'm facing to an error that I can't solve. When i'm submit my form to run the connection, I have this error :

```
No route matches [POST] "/login"
```

So I followed this [wiki/devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Display-a-custom-sign_in-form-anywhere-in-your-app) which deals with the subject. But is not working with the line :

```
helper_method :resource_name, :resource, :devise_mapping
```

I have this error :

> undefined method `helper_method' for PlainpageHelper:Module

For my last attempt, i'd try to add this lines into my routes file, but it's still not working

```
get 'login', to: 'sessions#new', as: 'login'
get 'logout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: 'logout'
get 'signup', to: 'users#new', as: 'signup'
```

My code :

My app (views/layout/application) =

```
  <%- if user_signed_in? %>
    <%= render 'partial/_connected'%>
  <% else %>
    <%= render 'partial/_disconnected'%>
  <% end %>
```

My form (views/partial/_disconnected) =

```
<li>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        Connection via
        <div class="social-buttons">
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-fb"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Facebook</a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-tw"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i> Twitter</a>
        </div>

         <form class="form" role="form" method="post" action="login" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="login-nav">
            <%= simple_form_for(resource, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>

              <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.input :email, required: false, autofocus: true %>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.input :password, required: false %>
              </div>         

              <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.submit "Connection", class: "btn btn-success" %>
              </div>
              <div class="checkbox">
                <%= f.input :remember_me, as: :boolean if devise_mapping.rememberable? %>
              </div>
            <% end %>
         </form>
      </div>
      <div class="bottom text-center">
        New here ? <a href="#"><b>Join Us</b></a>
      </div>
   </div>
</li>
```

The plain page helper :

```
module PlainpageHelper

  def resource_name
    :user
  end

  def resource
    @resource ||= User.new
  end

  def devise_mapping
    @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
  end

end
```

And finally my routes :

```
devise_for :users

  get 'plainpage/index'

  authenticated :user do
    root to: "plainpage#home", as: :authenticated_root
  end

  unauthenticated do
    root 'plainpage#index'
  end
```

So if you have any idea to solve this error, you'll be my hero !!
Thanks all, and good continuation !!

Answer (score 0):

Remove `<form class="form" role="form" method="post" action="login" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="login-nav">`, the `simple_form_for` will generate `form` tag, so it's duplicated.

And there is no need to add `resource_name, resource, devise_mapping` in module `PlainpageHelper`